# How to create an index with Distinct operation. RavenDB

Tags: c#, indexing, ravendb

What I need is to simply retrieve a list of categories stored in products:

`Products.Select(x => x.Category).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);`

When invoking this `RavenDB` says that I should use indexes instead cause computations aren't allowed during queries.

I have read a bit about indexes but still can't figure it out howcome I create an index?

What I have tried so far is:

**Initialization**

```
public class DataAccessModule : NinjectModule {
    public override void Load() {
        Bind<IDocumentStore>().ToMethod(
            context => {
               var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore {
                   DataDirectory = @"~/App_Data/database",
                   UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true,
                   DefaultDatabase = "SampleStore"
               };
               var store = documentStore.Initialize();
               IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(CategoriesIndex).Assembly, store);
               return store;
           }
       ).InSingletonScope();

        Bind<IDocumentSession>().ToMethod(context => 
            context.Kernel.Get<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession()
        ).InRequestScope();
    }
}
```

**Index definition**

```
public class CategoriesIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Product> {
    public CategoriesIndex() {
        Map = ct => ct.Select(x => x.Categories).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work.
Howcome I define it the right way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using:

```
var categories = Session.Query<Product>()
                   .Select(x => x.Category).Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(x=>x);
```

This will give you what you want.

Comment: is there no need to create an index then?